# React PWA Workbox InvalidStateError

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-window

Few users on IOS devices get error `InvalidStateError` `newestWorker is null`.

This is my register function using **workbox-window** just like the documentation mentioned

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const wb = new Workbox(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`)
    const showSkipWaitingPrompt = async (event) => {
        wb.addEventListener('controlling', () => {
            window.location.reload()
        })
        wb.messageSkipWaiting()
    }
    wb.addEventListener('waiting', (event) => {
        showSkipWaitingPrompt(event)
    })
    wb.register()
}
```

I call it on top level in index.js (main file)

And this is how I call the update:

```
const updateVersion = () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker?.getRegistrations().then((registrations) => {
        try {
            for (const reg of registrations) {
                reg.update()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.name !== 'InvalidStateError') {
                throw error   // here should be better error handling
            }
        }
    })
}

 const { pathname } = useLocation()   // from react-router-dom
 useEffect(() => {
     updateVersion()
 }, [pathname])
```

This is what I have in my service worker

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration'
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL, cleanupOutdatedCaches } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing'
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies'

clientsClaim();
cleanupOutdatedCaches();
precacheAndRoute((self as any).__WB_MANIFEST);
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
    ({ request, url }) => {
        if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
            return false;
        }

        if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
            return false;
        }

        if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    },
    createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        (self as any).skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

Why that error happens and how I can prevent / handle it? Should I somehow unregister and register the SW again?

- Workbox version 6.5.3
- React version: 18.2.0

No more information about the error exist.

Comment: I've started to see this too, did you discover anything?

Comment: It still appears sometimes. They released new version of Workbox, it might have something about this